# Remove self intersections from Bezier Path

Tags: ios, macos, core-graphics, bezier, cgpath

Let's assume we have a CGPath and we're drawing it with a **nonzero filling rule**. It may have self intersections, but it uses a Nonzero fill.

Now, for some reason, we have to switch to the **even-odd filling rule**. There is no other way. But we still want the path to look exactly the same as before. Therefore we have to do some modifications, like removing self intersections.

For example, this is what we have:

[image: Example 1]

But this is what we want:

[image: Example 2]

I added a gradient stroke to show the path, but i only care about the fill.

The result of this should be that we get a path without self intersections that looks the same when filled no matter what fill rule is used.
Note that the path may contain curve segments (not shown in the example)

So, my question is: How do i do this? :)

Comment: question is, why do you have to use even-odd fill?

Comment: @nielsbot: It's mainly because i'm trying to implement boolean operations on paths and that causes problems when they both have different fill rules...

Comment: small remark: your example image makes it seem like you're mistaking asking about Bezier curves because you don't mention them in your post, and your graphics are polygons. Secondary question: what have you tried so far, or what did you find while researching how to do this? ("do your research" is an important first step for stackoverflow questions)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: I wanted to have a simple example, but yeah, I need a solution for bézier curves...

Comment: to dispel any illusions: this is one of the really hard problems in vector graphics, so if CGPath has nothing built in to do this, my first suggestion would be to find a library that does this for you, and that you can simply pass your path information to (not necessarily as CGPath) and then get a new list of coordinates back. The problem is that a simple example is extremely misleading on how hard this is. Imagine a shape like ∞, what happens? It's self intersecting, but its shape does not cause even-odd/non-zero oddities. You'll still want to correct it, but is that now 1 or 2 shapes?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Yeah, you're probably right about that... do you know a library? I think for ∞, it could just be one path with a "move" segment in the middle...

Comment: Not without looking for one first, unfortunately. My Bezier game is pretty strong, but I've not worked with osx or ios...

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Maybe you know another library that can do this, i don't care if it's for OS X or iOS, would be nice to see the code. :)

Comment: You could have a look at the source of Clipper, http://www.angusj.com/delphi/clipper.php

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans: Unfortunately, it's only for polygons :(

Comment: hm, the problem is that I can trivially tell you how to find the intersections when Bezier curves are involved (hell, I wrote [half a book](http://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo) on all the things you can do with Bezier curves, as well as [a JS library](http://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/)) but shape resolution is much more work. You can look at the "BooleanComputer" source and follow the code, but I never got to making it robust so it'll fail on plenty of edge cases =/

Comment: I know it's been like, half a year, but one project that does solve this problem really well is [Paper.js](http://paperjs.org), which is also open source - if you were still wondering about how to do this (or some future visitor is) their source code would be a great starting place.